# awk add string to each line except last blank line

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have file with blank line at the end. I need to add suffix to each line except last blank line.

I use:

`awk '$0=$0"suffix"' | sed 's/^suffix$//'`

But maybe it can be done without `sed`?

UPDATE:

I want to skip all lines which contain only '\n' symbol.

EXAMPLE:

I have file `test.tsv`:

```
a\tb\t1\n
\t\t\n
c\td\t2\n
\n
```

I run `cat test.tsv | awk '$0=$0"\t2"' | sed 's/^\t2$//'`:

```
a\tb\t1\t2\n
\t\t\t2\n
c\td\t2\t2\n
\n
```

Comment: Do you want to skip all the blank lines or just the last blank line?

Comment: Just last blank line.

Comment: It can be non-blank. And I want to skip only last line if it blank.

Comment: In my use-case blank lines is only lines witch contain only one '\n' symbol. I'm working with tab-separated files, so line with few tabs isn't blank for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you need:

```
awk 'NR>1{print prev "suffix"} {prev=$0} END{ if (NR) print prev (prev == "" ? "" : "suffix") }' file
```

The test for NR in the END is to avoid printing a blank line given an empty input file. It's untested, of course, since you didn't provide any sample input/output in your question.

To treat all empty lines the same:

```
awk '{print $0 (/./ ? "suffix" : "")}' file
```

Comment: Could it be simplier if we avoid skip all lines == '\n', not only last?

Comment: Could you please add that variant?

Comment: I want to print such lines "as it is" without modification. Ok, I'll update question.

Comment: Ok, sorry for delay. I'll test your second command right now.

Comment: Good give it a few hours to see if you get a better answer and THEN accept the best one for you.

Answer (score 2):

@try:

```
awk 'NF{print $0 "suffix"}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

this will skip all blank lines

```
awk 'NF{$0=$0 "suffix"}1' file
```

to only skip the last line if blank

```
 awk 'NR>1{print p "suffix"} {p=$0} END{print p (NF?"suffix":"") }' file
```

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov: Glad that it helped you, if that is right answer then kindly mark it as correct answer too. It will help people who will refer this thread in future too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 ok, just need some time to accept according SO rules

Comment: I agree with Ed here, wanted to just encourage user to mark answers as solved for the future references.

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` is okay:

```
$ cat ip.txt 
a   b   1

c   d   2

$ perl -lpe '$_ .= "\t 2" if !(eof && /^$/)' ip.txt 
a   b   1    2
             2
c   d   2    2

$ # no blank line for empty file as well
$ printf '' | perl -lpe '$_ .= "\t 2" if !(eof && /^$/)'
$
```

- `-l` strips newline from input, adds back when line is printed at end of code due to `-p` option
- `eof` to check end of file
- `/^$/` blank line
- `$_ .= "\t 2"` append to input line

Comment: It's ok, but I'm not sure if it fast like awk. I'm working with very big files)

Comment: oh okay :) but if you get a chance to try it out, let me know the time difference...

Comment: Seems like `awk` is slightly faster:

`time zcat test.tsv.gz | perl -lpe '$_ .= "\t 2" if !(eof && /^$/)' > test.tsv

real 0m2.919s
user 0m3.828s
sys 0m0.564s

time zcat test.tsv.gz | awk '{print $0 (/./ ? "\t2" : "")}' > test.tsv

real 0m2.682s
user 0m3.124s
sys 0m0.544s`

Size of test.tsv.gz is 79Mb.

Comment: Sorry for formating. User time is 3.124s vs 3.828s between awk and perl.

Comment: sorry but `awk '{print $0 (/./ ? "\t2" : "")}'` will add the suffix for all non-empty lines... which conflicts with `I have file with blank line at the end. I need to add suffix to each line except last blank line`... equivalent one is `perl -lpe '$_ .= "\t 2" if !/^$/'` .. not that I am doubting awk is better choice here

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$ cat f ###Blank line only in the end of file
-11.2
hello

$ awk '{print (/./?$0"suffix":"")}' f
-11.2suffix
hellosuffix

$
```

OR

```
$ cat f  ####blank line in middle and end of file
-11.2

hello

$ awk -v val=$(wc -l < f) '{print (/./ || NR!=val?$0"suffix":"")}' f
-11.2suffix
suffix
hellosuffix

$
```